# Playing UDP streams in HTML5

Tags: stream, udp, html5-video, multicast

This question has come up before but I dont see any uptodate information. I am receiving a UDP stream which I want to display in a browser using HTML5. The stream is UDP multicast for general TV channels, which is in H.264 format. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Web browsers works with TCP only, that's why flash was needed to play videos on web browsers. As an isolated thread it could use udp or rtmp and many other protocols. You may look for m3u8 as a workaround. Good luck.